# Firebase. Using Google authentication with the same email used on Facebook auth. creates another user with the same id

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

It still has all connections and conversations that original user has ( which used Facebook auth provider method) . The problem is, now i have two users with the same id which means any query relationated to that id will have duplicated results with different avatars, maybe names etc.. So how can i delete the original user after google auth provider duplicates it?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you getting 2 users with the same `uid`? That shouldn't be possible. If so, you should report it to Firebase support. Otherwise please rephrase your question with more details.

Comment: Yup. Nothing to clarify. Same uid, somehow same access to connections, messages etc... and the other users relationated to the original one have them both on their contact list. GoogleAuthProvider just clones the original user leaving him there instead of removing (at least).

Comment: I still confuse, so there is a user login with gmail with email like sharedemail@gmail.com. Then there is anoother person login with facebook but the email is sharedemail@gmail.com. Then they get same userId?? I think its their mistake, one person should never share their email right?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this behaviour in the Firebase console?